# I don't understand the meaning of 'profess'. in this sentence

Tags: word-meaning

> Never before had statesmen and philosophers laid so much stress
>   on the importance of any and all men. Never before had they **professed** to
>   take so little account of.

A Longman dictionary says that 'profess' means you say
something when it is not true.
But it does not make sense to me.

This comes from the book 'The Modern Views of Man' written by J.W. Krutch.

Comment: Could you add a link to the definition you are referring to?

Comment: That definition (saying something that's not true) is an unusual one. The most common meaning for *profess* is to state a position (usually publicly).

Comment: @Era - I thought the same thing. One synonym for _profess_ in this context might be [_claim_](https://wordnik.com/words/profess).

Answer (score 1):

To **profess** is to **declare** *something* without ambiguity

> He **professed** his love for her.
>   They **professed** their allegiance to the king.

Not sure why OP's definition has to do with lying.

Comment: Google definition says "claim openly but often falsely that one has (a quality or feeling)" - which caught me by surprise.